# R function to summarize based on condition (sum x[y>0])

Tags: r, aggregate

My question is the following.

Say I have a data.frame with an identifier "A" for each measurement in the dataset. Also, I have a value for time (numerical) and a value for difference (numerical). The dataset looks something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(Identifier = c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A"),
                 Time_between = c(15, 25, 5, 6, 17, 9, 28, 3),
                 Difference = c(3, 15, -8, 7, 16, 29, 2, 0))
#>   Identifier Time_between Difference
#> 1          A           15          3
#> 2          A           25         15
#> 3          A            5         -8
#> 4          A            6          7
#> 5          A           17         16
#> 6          A            9         29
#> 7          A           28          2
#> 8          A            3          0
```

What I would like to achieve is a cumulative value for Time_between, but only using the values that related to difference >0. Thus, the third value of difference being -8 should conclude the value "5" not being used in the cumulative value.

I have tried writing a function wherein:

```
sum_if<- function(h,i){
  sum(h[i>0])}
```

but using this function in aggregate gave me multiple error messages:

```
trial<-aggregate(df$time_between, by=df["Identifier"],    
                    FUN=function(h,i) sum_if(df$time_between, df$diff))    
Error in sum(h[i > 0]) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument
```

My dataframe is very large (>1 million observations x 25 variables) so this is a very much simplified version of what I work with.

Additionally I would like to get at a point where given a smaller than 0 value the summation restarts.

---

Additional information after having tried some of the answers suggested.

I ran into some problems. Discussing the first option using plyr does work in the dataset I created in this post but becomes problematic when applying it in the bigger dataset I have available. Something maybe a bit more realistic:

```
df <- data.frame(Identifier = c("A","A","B","C","C","C","D","E"),
             Time_between = c(NA, 25, NA, NA, 17, 9, NA, NA),
             Difference = c(NA, 15, NA, NA, 16, -239, NA, NA))
```

The NAs are informative and should therefore not be ignored. For instance:
If identifier A has one NA and 25 ("time between") this means the second prescription was timed 25 days after the first. The difference is 15 if for instance the first time something was prescribed was at timepoint 10, and the next at timepoint 25.

I tried the first option using:

```
 df_trial<- df_trial %>% group_by(Studienummer) %>% 
  mutate(condsumPlyr=cumsum(df_trial$time_between)*(df_trial$diff_A>0)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

This resulted in an error:
***Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `condsumPlyr`.
x Input `condsumPlyr` can't be recycled to size 1.
i Input `condsumPlyr` is `cumsum(df_trial$time_between) * (df_trial$diff_A > 0)`.
i Input `condsumPlyr` must be size 1, not 10576.
i The error occured in group 1: Identifier= 59.***

The 2nd thing I tried was using:

```
df_trial[,(consumDT:= cumsum(time_between*(diff_A>0))), by=Identifier]
```

Which wouldn't work, error: ***unused argument (by=Identifier)***

Lastly, using the following code:

```
df_trial$cumsumBR <- sapply(split(df_trial, df_trial$Studienummer), 
  function(df_trial)cumsum(df_trial$time_between * (df_trial$diff_A > 0)))
```

The following error occured: ***Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, cumsumBR, value = list(`59` = NA_real_,  :
replacement has 3106 rows, data has 10576***

I am uncertain which option holds my preferred result, but they all don't seem to work.

**Side-note**: On the 'simple' dataset I had given I did get the expected results. Thanks!

Comment: Is it just one value per `Identifier`?

Comment: Each individual "person" in my data has their unique identifier. But I'm trying it with one identifier, in the actual dataset there are over 100.000 unique identifiers.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep your structure you can use a boolean to simulate an `ifelse` (faster than `ifelse`), and use `cumsum` to get the cummulative sum. Using `dplyr` we can get a readable expression for performing the calculations.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df <- df %>% 
  group_by(Identifier) %>% 
  mutate(condsumdPlyr = cumsum(Time_between * (Difference > 0))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

in `data.table` or `disk.frame` we'd use their standard notation

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(df) #change df to data.table
df[, consumDT := cumsum(Time_between * ( Difference > 0 ) ), by = Identifier]
# Alternative: df[Difference > 0, consumDT := cumsum(Time_between), by = Identifier]
setDF(df) #Only to change it back to a data.frame
```

In base `R` we'd like to use `aggregate` but as we need to use multiple columns, it is simpler to do with `split` and `sapply` (similar to how `tapply` works for arrays)

```r
df$consumBase <- sapply(split(df, df$Identifier), function(df)cumsum(df$Time_between * (df$Difference > 0)))
```

Now if you're stone hard on using `aggregate` life becomes a lot more complicated, as it is intended for single column aggregation. We can get part-way by using the `subset` argument, but this removes the correct indices and makes it difficult to merge the result with our original `data.frame`

```r
condDf <- aggregate(Time_between ~ Identifier, data = df, FUN = cumsum, subset = df$Difference > 0)
condDf <- data.frame(Identifier = rep(condDf$Identifier, lengths(condDf$Time_between)), condsumAggregate = unlist(condDf$Time_between))
```

Ofc. if we  `length(unique(df$Identifier))` is 1, this becomes simpler as we do not need to group our data.

**Disclaimer:** Without data there is no way for me to properly test this for spelling error

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try your feedback. I'm already very pleased to see some different ideas than the ones I found in my google search.

Will keep you posted and will also add some data if it doesn't work.

Comment: If the dataset becomes **large** (very large that is), `data.table` is going to be a better fitting option. `df[Difference > 0, consumDT := cumsum(Time_between), by = Identifier]` The syntax is a bit harder for most but takes inspiration from SQL.